# How can I obtain CPack's default/fallback install prefix?

Tags: cmake, packaging, cpack

I am using CMake to build my project and now I want to use CPack to create Linux packages (starting with a DEB package). I have things set up such that I can generated a DEB package now, but there is one problem that I am not entirely sure how I should solve it.

During compilation, I am also generating a systemd service file for my application that necessarily contains the absolute path to where my application is installed to. No big problem as we have `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` which enables us to get the needed path that is in agreement to where things are installed to when one executes `make install`.

However, `cpack` seems to use a different install prefix (`/usr/` instead of `/usr/local/`) and therefore the path in the service file inside my DEB package, doesn't match to where the generated package actually installs the executable to.

After a bit of research, I found [CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) which apparently allows me to override cpack's default, but that is not quite what I want. I would like CPack to do its thing, but I need a way to essentially anticipate where CPack wants to install things to in order to configure my service file correctly. The linked docs also state that

> Each CPack generator has a default value

Indicating that the chosen path is generator-dependent.

Now, it would be possible to figure out where e.g. the DEB generator installs things to and then manually set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` to that same value so that the service file configuration works as expected, but I would like to avoid having such a manual step in the process.
Therefore my question: Is there a way to determine at configure time what path a given CPack generator will use as the install prefix? Or even better: have a way to automatically reconfigure certain files when CPack runs and then adapt the respective paths on-the-fly without having to modify the files configured during a regular CMake invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is- there's no super easy way from a CPack package-author's perspective. I did a grep through CMake's `Modules/` folder and didn't find the default/fallback being set there. It turns out it's set as a default/fallback value in the CPack binary's source code. You can see for yourself: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/search?q=SetOptionIfNotSet+CPACK_PACKAGING_INSTALL_PREFIX, where you'll see (at the time of this writing):

- cmCPackGenerator.cxx (which I'm guessing is the default if a specific generator doesn't override it): `/`
- cmCPackCygwinBinaryGenerator.cxx: `/usr`
- cmCPackDebGenerator.cxx: `/usr`
- cmCPackFreeBSDGenerator.cxx: `/usr/local`
- cmCPackProductBuildGenerator.cxx: `/Applications`
- cmCPackRPMGenerator.cxx: `/usr`

So if you want to mirror that logic in your own CPack config scripts, you'll have to do so yourself. You could look at using the value of [`CPACK_GENERATOR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_GENERATOR) in a [`CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#variable:CPACK_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE) (note that [`CPACK_GENERATOR` means different things in different script contexts](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CPack.html#cpack-generators)).

Comment: Thanks for digging this up. I already suspected that there is likely no easy solution, but thanks to your research I am no pretty sure there can't be one. Guess it is workaround time then...